# Can a simple linear regression be applied to a time series with non-constant time interval between observations?

Tags: regression, time-series, prediction

I have a strictly ordered series of observations where the time between the observation is not constant. I am wondering if I can apply a simple linear regression on this and treat it as I would treat a time series with a constant time interval between observations?

In other words - is it a necessary for the linear regression model to hold that the time interval between observations are consant?

Comment: Do you know the actual times of the observations in question?

Comment: yes I can find that out, but preferably I'd like to skip it

Comment: Be aware that if you include lagged regressors, the timing becomes relevant. In that case, you need evenly spaced regressors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The simplest case is if that there is no dependence between your errors.

If your model is 
$$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \left[ x_{t,1} \beta_2 + \cdots + x_{t,p}\beta_{p+1} \right]+ \epsilon_t$$
where $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_T \overset{iid}{\sim} \text{Normal}(0, \sigma^2)$, $t$ is time, and the $xs$ are some arbitrary covariates/predictors, then you can use ordinary least squares to estimate the $\beta$s. If your times are irregularly sampled, the model still holds as long as the length of time between observations has nothing to do with the errors.

If there is some structure in your errors, then you will have to worry about how to estimate the covariance matrix of all the $\epsilon_t$s, and use something like generalized least squares.

Answer (score 0):

Linear regression does not make any assumptions about evenly spaced observations, so you should be fine.

On the other hand you might consider weighting your samples, depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: It doesn't assume they are evenly spaced, but it will need to be told what the spacing *is*.

Comment: Sure, but if you do linear regression you can't avoid putting that information into the model. I assumed that the model is understood, including which data has to be put into it (data matrix X, response vector Y, where the first column of X is 1's and the second the time data, if you want to model the intercept of the regression, or only the column of time data if the intercept of the line should be 0.
The more interesting question would be how the observations would have to be weighted to account for the different spacings. Data points far from other data may have to be amplified.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. I was planning on running regress(Y,X) where Y is response vector and X is a column of 1's and a column of some data. I have no intention on weighting, and am basically wondering if the regression model still holds (i.e. I do not break any assumptions).

Comment: @mindleaving, of course it is quite reasonable to assume that the OP would know to put that information into the model, but notice the comments under the original question. The OP would "like to skip it". I suspect that it might be worth clarifying the necessity of putting that information into the model.